# Indexing in TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb

Today I read on [Hackernews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19270667) about [BRIN indexing with PostgreSQL](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/postgresql-brin-indexes-big-data-performance-with-minimal-storage).

We are working with TimescaleDB for large and simple sensor data series.

Does BRIN indexing in TimescaleDB give additional value or do TimescaleDB features make BRIN indexing obsolete?

Comment: I doubt BRIN index would help improving performance for simple sensor data stored in TimescaleDB. Try using alternative TSDBs, which could give higher performance or lower CPU and disk usage. For instance, InfluxDB, VictoriaMetrics, M3DB. See also [this article](https://medium.com/@valyala/measuring-vertical-scalability-for-time-series-databases-in-google-cloud-92550d78d8ae).

Answer (score 1):

TimescaleDB is just a thin layer that speeds up inserting into partitions, it doesn't boost your queries to the best of my knowledge.

BRIN indexes are only useful in the case when the logical ordering of the rows according to a column is the exact same (or the exact opposite) of the physical ordering of the rows.

In practice, that means that rows have to be inserted in the same order as the column in question (e.g., earlier timestamps get inserted before later ones), and there is never an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

If this is the case, you can use a BRIN index on that column, which will take almost no space.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be exactely our case. We insert sensor data always with now() timestamp. I‘ll try this definitely!

Comment: Timescale person here.  

Just to be clear, Timescale provides a number of changes around query planning/optimizations for nature & scale of time-series data, as well as other capabilities for new analytics and automated time-series data management.  So not just a "thin layer over inserts", but perhaps I'm being pedantic.

Regarding Q:  Timescale supports BRIN indexes; when created on hypertable will propagate to BRIN index local to each chunk.

One thing to be careful, alluded to by Laurenz: you can still have reordering around now() in you have any amount of concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; as you may have guessed, I have no deep knowledge of TimescaleDB.